# Sitecore 9 : Install-SitecoreConfiguration : No registration found for extension 'AppPool' of type 'Task'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore9

I have followed Sitecore 9 installation steps by using this link:
[A step by step guide for Sitecore 9 installation on your machine](https://buoctrenmay.com/2017/10/30/a-step-by-step-guide-for-sitecore-9-installation-on-your-machine/).

I have successfully installed SolR server, then after that, I have registered Sitecore Nuget repository and also installed related module

```
Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework

Install-Module SitecoreFundamentals

Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework

Import-Module SitecoreFundamentals
```

Then after I have tried to run shell script but got the following exception

```
.\InstallSitecore9.ps1

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : No registration found for extension 'AppPool' of type 'Task'.
At C:\sitecore\install\InstallSitecore9.ps1:48 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
```

Comment: Hi Kapil, were you able to resolve this issue? Could you please reply back with some inputs if yes ?

Comment: @AminSayed if you were able to resolve this error, please guide

Comment: @Imad - I did. But this was long ago, don't remember this. The only thing I can say is to copy these module folders from the Single-Developer installation instance. What I did was I installed Single-Developer instance in my personal machine and copied these files in UAT instance, if you are setting up distributed instance (like UAT, PROD)

Answer (score 4):

I found attempting to execute the 9.3 scripts in powershell v7 caused these errors. Switching to a v5 powershell session resolved the issue.

Comment: Wonderful, this happened for 10.2 installation and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just review your IIS settings, you may have something like below :
[image]

Comment: To be clear this answer is saying the settings in the comment image under "Web Management Tools" that are checked _**should**_ be checked and this was indeed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have just got the same issue and resolved it by running the following cmdlet:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\Prerequisites.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation and got same error even after updating the IIS settings and installing Sitecore prerequisites as suggested in previous answers. I was on Sitecore 10.3 Update 1. I had to restart PowerShell window and then restarted machine to make the changes from .\Prerequisites.json to be effective.

Both the previous answers (setting internet settings and running script to install Sitecore prerequisites) take you a step ahead in solving the problem, but this additional step is what is missing if the problem still persists. Hence, posting this as an answer.